# Connecting Django to Postgres: django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: database "DATABASENAME" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have just started learning Django after I took some tutorials for Python.

I am trying to connect my POSTGRES database to the Django project I have just created.

However, I am experiencing this problem:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "producthuntdb" does not exist
```

I followed these steps:

1) Opened postgress by clicking its icon

2) Clicked on the database "postgress". The terminal opened and I wrote: `CREATE DATABASE producthuntdb`; The database has been created because I see it if I open postgress via its icon.

3) Went to my Django project in "settings" and change the SQLITE database to the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'producthuntdb',
        'USER': 'mymac2017',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

4) Run the code `python3 manage.py migrate`

However, I am getting the error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "producthuntdb" does not exist`

So I did the following:

- Cliking on postgress icon and opening the the database `producthuntdb`
- Once the terminal is open, I wrote: `\du`
- There are two users with the attributes:

  1) mymac2017 | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}

  2) postgres         | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to look other answers to this problem and most of the issues are from misspelling the database name OR not creating it. However, the name of my database is correct and I can see the database `producthuntdb` if I open postgres.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the user has access to the database?

Comment: I am sure about the database name. I am NOT sure how to check if the user has access to the database.
I tried to click on "producthuntdb", and writre in the terminal "\du". There are two users, one of which is the same i wrote for "'USER': 'postgres'".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Wouldn't that raise an `access denied` error?

Comment: Did you try restart the postgresql service?

Comment: I tried to close and open again postgres (via clicking "quit") but I am not sure if it is what you mean, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set the wrong port of the Database in the Django "settings.py".

I was using `'PORT': '5432'` instead of `'PORT': '5433'`

**SOLUTION:**

- Go to your Postgres app/icon/program
- Click on "Server setting" and see which PORT the database POSTGRES is using
- Be sure that the PORT the database is using is the same as the one you write in the "settings.py" of your Django project.